# How to implement Incremental loading in MasterDetailsView?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I want to implement Incremental loading in [`MasterDetailsView`](http://www.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/controls/MasterDetailsView/). I know we can implement Incremental loading with [`ISupportIncremental​Loading`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.ISupportIncrementalLoading). But one problem I don't have all the items in the `ObservableCollection` at once. The items in `ObservableCollection` will be added only when the user reach the end of the `MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate`.

I have already created a function to load more Items in `ObservableCollection` but I want to call that function only when the user reaches the end of the `MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate`.

So how do I do it?

Comment: Maybe something like pagination? Bind scroll event and when it reaches the end of that particular item just load another one.

Comment: @m.rogalski How to Bind scroll event? Can you please explain it with a code?

Comment: I haven't done it but from what I remember MasterDetailsView contains a ListView as a placeholder for each Item. And inside ListView you should have property called VerticalOffset.

Comment: My bad, Inside ListView you have to get first possible ScrollViewer : `GetDescendants(<NameOfListView>).OfType<ScrollViewer>().FirstOrDefault()` and this will have VerticalOffset property.

Comment: @m.rogalski Can you explain it in detail with a code? I have never used VerticalOffset property

Comment: UWP Community Toolkit has [IncrementalLoadingCollection](http://docs.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/helpers/IncrementalLoadingCollection/) you should check that out.

Comment: @AVKNaidu To use IncrementalLoadingCollection we must have all the item in the collection.

Comment: `To use IncrementalLoadingCollection we must have all the item in the collection`, I have to disagree. If you see the `GetPagedItemsAsync`, You can always add items to the collection and then get the only items that are added. Check this [GitHub](https://github.com/avknaidu/IncrementalLoading) Repo. I Modified existing Example to add New Items on ScrollDown.

Comment: @AVKNaidu I will try and let you know the result

Comment: @AVKNaidu It works. I will answer my own question so that everyone else can learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can implement Incremental loading with [Incremental Loading Collection](http://www.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/helpers/IncrementalLoadingCollection/)

```
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp;

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class PeopleSource : IIncrementalSource<Person>
{
    private readonly List<Person> people;

    public async Task<IEnumerable<InfoOverView>> GetPagedItemsAsync(int pageIndex, int pageSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        return AddItems();
    }

    public void AddItems()
    {
        people.Clear();
        //Code to add the additional items in the people List
        return people;
    }
}

//In Page.xaml.cs
public Page()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    var collection = new IncrementalLoadingCollection<PeopleSource, Person>();
    MasterDetailsViewPanel.ItemsSource = collection;
}
```